# Getting valueForKey returns (null)

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to put a value in a NSArray and receive it again later.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_system setValue:[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"selected"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", [_system valueForKey:@"selected"]);
}
```

Here is the log result:

```
2013-11-01 23:38:04.210 ClassPoints[187:60b] test
2013-11-01 23:38:04.211 ClassPoints[187:60b] (null)
```

What I find odd is even creating the array in the void doesn't properly load the value.

```
NSArray *testArray;
[testArray setValue:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
NSLog(@"%@", [testArray valueForKey:@"test"]);
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?  I am completely lost.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `NSArray` an `NSMutableArray` so you can edit objects in it and in your viewDidLoad do not forget to initialize it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Nothing still.  This is really weird, because I know I've used this many times before without issue.  There's got to be something super small I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Once an NSArray has been initialized, you won't be able to add/remove/edit objects on it. That is what an NSMutableArray is for.

Comment: 'NSMutableArray *testArray;
    [testArray setValue:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [testArray valueForKey:@"test"]);' still returns (null)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this use `NSMutableArray` and for setting use `setObject` api inspite of setting setValue.

```
 NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray array];
 [testArray setObject:@"test" forKey:@"test"];
 NSLog(@"%@", [testArray objectForKey:@"test"]);
```

Comment: No visible interface for setObject and objectForKey

Comment: I did not get and also this interface is only for mutablearray

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use the mutable versions of the collection type you want to use, then you need to alloc and init them. Then unless your _system (NSArray?) contains objects that are key value coding compliant for "selected". `setValue:forKey` calls setValue:forKey on each of your arrays elements. The same applies for `valueForKey:`. Thats why your isolated example wont work either. I think you want a `NSMutableDictionary` then you can get/set objects through keys while arrays only works with indexes.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:yourObject forKey:yourKey];
id obj = [dictionary objectForKey:yourKey];
```